# Postgres and slow forward index scan?

Tags: postgresql

Could anyone throw any ideas, why on Postgres following simple query is 600x slower doing forward index scan than a backward scan (usually this is other way around):

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

vs

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" ORDER BY "events"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Id is a primary key column. Both queries produce exact same plan with exact same estimates. Only difference is backwards scan.

Other one takes 30ms and the other 0.05ms execution time.

--

EDIT: primary key type is bigint

--

EDIT: add query plans

````
-> Index Scan using events_pkey on events (cost=0.57..747008554.20 rows=200288464 width=1153) (actual time=29.662..29.6...
Planning Time: 0.090 ms
Execution Time: 29.694 ms```

—

```Limit (cost=0.57..4.30 rows=1 width=1153) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows= 1 loops=1)
-> Index Scan Backward using events_pkey on events (cost=0.57..747008554.20 rows=200288464 width=1153) (actual time=0....
Planning Time: 0.089 ms
Execution Time: 0.049 ms
````

--

EDIT: Query times stays the same regardless of cold or warm query. ANALYZE or VACUUM don't have any effect.

Comment: Please share Bothe query plans, in plain text, using explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings). The ddl for the table and indexes involved would be nice as well. Without this information we can't see what's going on

Comment: "*Only difference is backwards scan.*" - I'd say the main difference is which row is selected! This requires loading different pages of the index and table into memory, which are probably already cached in one case and need to be read from disk in the other.

Comment: Added more information; query plans and primary column type

Comment: (actual time=0.... And where is the rest? And please use explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) and share the entire plan, not half of it.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head, I'd ask:

- What is the type of the `id` column?
- what is the insertion pattern ? (batches of sequential ids?)

I'm asking this because UUIDs or other random values will have a higher chance to hit different leaves of the b-tree, and thus tend to reduce cache hits when traversing them sequentially.

Indexes can be created with an [`order by` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html).

Comment: Yes. Adding different kind of index probably solves this, this is more out of curiosity and an attempt to learn about postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by doing a full vacuum. This was new for me. I don't know the usage patterns of the table as I'm just admin of db's but I guess there has been a lot of modifications recently to that table?

Previously regular autovacuum has been enough.

Comment: Perhaps bloat. I'd research in that direction the next time the problem comes up.